# What is the Julia equivalent to Python's schedule package?

Tags: julia, scheduling

I have a piece of Python code which a want to convert to Julia. I the python code I use the [schedule](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule) package. What is the equivalent in Julia, I looked at the "Tasks and Parallel Computing" part in the Julia documentation but I can't find something similar. The code in Python is:

```
def main():
    schedule.every(0.25).seconds.do(read_modbus, 1, 1000, 100, 1)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: What's the use case exactly? i.e. is there a reason you can't just `while true; println("hello\n"); sleep(0.25); end`

Comment: That will not help, I don't know how much time the call to the read_modbus function is going to take but I want to run it 4 times per second.

Comment: If you try `def read_modbus(*a): print(datetime.datetime.now());time.sleep(0.19)` you'll see that function is called only approximately 2 times per second although there is space to run it 4 times. (if you change `schedule.every(0.25)` to `schedule.every(0.001)` it will be called approximately 4 times!). I think it is because next run is scheduled [**after work is done**](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/schedule/__init__.py#L386)

Comment: I know the read_modbus function is fast enough (most of the time) so it will fit in .25 seconds. The function will take a couple of ms to execute but I can't exactly predict how much time it is going to take. So a sleep after the function call is not going to help.

Comment: But I am trying to say that sleep(0.25) after the function call has same behavior. My example simulate read_modbus running 0.19s so it fit into 0.25 limit (also with 0.05 sleep in while cycle). But function is called approximately every 0.49s. Just copy my function and try it in your main function!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will a [`Timer`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/#Base.Timer-Tuple%7BFunction,Real,Real%7D) work? This form of `Timer` calls your function in a [`Task`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/parallel/#Tasks-1) so you need to yield control from you main loop occasionally to allow the timer task to run. You can yield by calling `yield`, `sleep`, `wait`, or doing IO, here I show waiting on the timer.

```
tstart = time()
ncalls = 0
read_modbus() = (global ncalls+=1;@show (time()-tstart)/ncalls,ncalls)
t=Timer((timer)->read_modbus(),0,0.25)

while true
    wait(t) # wait for timer to go off
    println("mainloop $ncalls")
end
```

Comment: Yes! :) This `read_modbus() = (global ncalls,tstart;println((time()-tstart)/(ncalls!=0?ncalls:1)," ",ncalls);sleep(0.24);ncalls+=1);tstart = time();ncalls = 0;t=Timer((timer)->read_modbus(),0,0.25);` is working as I expect. But I didn't expect that this `read_modbus() = (global ncalls,tstart;println((time()-tstart)/(ncalls!=0?ncalls:1)," ",ncalls);sleep(0.5);ncalls+=1);tstart = time();ncalls = 0;t=Timer((timer)->read_modbus(),0,0.25);` will converge to 0.75s ...

Comment: I was also looking for a Julia scheduler...  (to replace Python APScheduler in my case) see https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-cron-like-event-scheduler/6899/2

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that a scheduling library for [Julia](https://julialang.org/) was missing so I wrote one https://github.com/scls19fr/ExtensibleScheduler.jl

Here is a basic example using a blocking scheduler.

```
using ExtensibleScheduler

function read_modbus(p1, p2, p3, p4)
    println("Read_modbus with $p1 $p2 $p3 $p4")
end

sched = BlockingScheduler()

add(sched, Action(read_modbus, 1, 1000, 100, 1), Trigger(Dates.Millisecond(250)))

run(sched)
```

Althought, this is a work in progress but contributers are welcome.

Currently (2017-12), there is only an implementation of a blocking scheduler but it should be possible to add multithreading.